# Need help in regex matching

Tags: java, regex

It may be very simple, but I am extremely new to regex and have a requirement where I need to do some regex matches in a string and extract the number in it. Below is my code with sample i/p and required o/p.  I tried to construct the `Pattern` by referring to https://www.freeformatter.com/java-regex-tester.html, but my regex match itself is returning false.

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".*/(a-b|c-d|e-f)/([0-9])+(#[0-9]?)");
String str = "foo/bar/Samsung-Galaxy/a-b/1"; // need to extract 1.
String str1 = "foo/bar/Samsung-Galaxy/c-d/1#P2";// need to extract 2.
String str2 = "foo.com/Samsung-Galaxy/9090/c-d/69"; // need to extract 69

System.out.println("result " + pattern.matcher(str).matches());
System.out.println("result " + pattern.matcher(str1).matches());
System.out.println("result " + pattern.matcher(str1).matches());
```

All of above SOPs are returning false. I am using java 8, is there is any way by which in a single statement I can match the pattern and then extract the **digit** from the string.

I would be great if somebody can point me on how to debug/develop the regex.Please feel free to let me know if something is not clear in my question.

Comment: Thanks for answers, I am trying to understand all the answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".*/(?:a-b|c-d|e-f)/[^/]*?([0-9]+)");
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/9B5Lg9/2)

When used with `matches()`, the pattern above does not require explicit anchors, `^` and `$`.

**Details**

- `.*` - any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as many as possible
- `/` - the rightmost `/` that is followed with the subsequent subpatterns
- `(?:a-b|c-d|e-f)` - a non-capturing group matching any of the alternatives inside: `a-b`, `c-d` or `e-f`
- `/` - a `/` char
- `[^/]*?` - any chars other than `/`, as few as possible
- `([0-9]+)` - Group 1: one or more digits.

[Java demo](https://ideone.com/d2U5Tk):

```
List<String> strs = Arrays.asList("foo/bar/Samsung-Galaxy/a-b/1","foo/bar/Samsung-Galaxy/c-d/1#P2","foo.com/Samsung-Galaxy/9090/c-d/69");
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".*/(?:a-b|c-d|e-f)/[^/]*?([0-9]+)");
for (String s : strs) {
    Matcher m = pattern.matcher(s);
    if (m.matches()) {
        System.out.println(s + ": \"" + m.group(1) + "\"");
    }
}
```

A replacing approach using the same regex with anchors added:

```
List<String> strs = Arrays.asList("foo/bar/Samsung-Galaxy/a-b/1","foo/bar/Samsung-Galaxy/c-d/1#P2","foo.com/Samsung-Galaxy/9090/c-d/69");
String pattern = "^.*/(?:a-b|c-d|e-f)/[^/]*?([0-9]+)$";
for (String s : strs) {
    System.out.println(s + ": \"" + s.replaceFirst(pattern, "$1") + "\"");
}
```

See [another Java demo](https://ideone.com/H5vXmZ).

Output:

```
foo/bar/Samsung-Galaxy/a-b/1: "1"
foo/bar/Samsung-Galaxy/c-d/1#P2: "2"
foo.com/Samsung-Galaxy/9090/c-d/69: "69"
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer and nice explanation. I have below doubts

Comment: @user7851946 Yes?

Comment: @user7851946 What are the doubts?

Comment: I am sure that after `a-b`, `c-d` it can contain only digit after "/" or digit followed by `#P(some digit)`, then can I modified my regex to `Pattern.compile("(.*)/(?:a-b|c-d|e-f)/([0-9])(#P[0-9])?");` ?

Comment: Sorry for the late response but after some googling and some code try, I understood your regex completely :)

Comment: @user7851946 There are other digits in the last subpart, thus, you cannot use just a `[0-9]` pattern. If the pattern is stricter, i.e. if there may be any 0+ digits followed with `#P` before the number you want to extract, you may use `(?:[0-9]*#P)?` there instead of a more generic `[^/]*?`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/9B5Lg9/4).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182348/discussion-between-user7851946-and-wiktor-stribizew).

Answer (score 1):

Because you match always the last number in your regex, I would Like to just use `replaceAll` with this regex `.*?(\d+)$` :

```
String regex = ".*?(\\d+)$";

String strResult1 = str.replaceAll(regex, "$1");
System.out.println(!strResult1.isEmpty() ? "result " + strResult1 : "no result");

String strResult2 = str1.replaceAll(regex, "$1");
System.out.println(!strResult2.isEmpty() ? "result " + strResult2 : "no result");

String strResult3 = str2.replaceAll(regex, "$1");
System.out.println(!strResult3.isEmpty() ? "result " + strResult3 : "no result");
```

If the result is empty then you don't have any number.

Outputs

```
result 1
result 2
result 69
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a one-liner using `String#replaceAll`:

```
public String getDigits(String input) {
    String number = input.replaceAll(".*/(?:a-b|c-d|e-f)/[^/]*?(\\d+)$", "$1");
    return number.matches("\\d+") ? number : "no match";
}

System.out.println(getDigits("foo.com/Samsung-Galaxy/9090/c-d/69"));
System.out.println(getDigits("foo/bar/Samsung-Galaxy/a-b/some other text/1"));
System.out.println(getDigits("foo/bar/Samsung-Galaxy/9090/a-b/69ace"));

69
no match
no match
```

This works on the sample inputs you provided.  Note that I added logic which will display `no match` for the case where ending digits could not be matched fitting your pattern.  In the case of a non-match, we would typically be left with the original input string, which would not be all digits.

Comment: When using `.*?`, there is a chance the regex will match `a-b` alternative before the last `/` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/9B5Lg9/3)) and it might be something OP does not expect.